# How do I change where an object goes when I press Alt+G

Tags: rigging, objects, armature, bones, origin

So i am trying to create a rig. I want to make it so if i move say the arm or the eyeball, and I don't wanna have to keep undoing., how could I make it so i could just press Alt-G, and the object snaps back to where I want it?

Answer (score 0):

By definition <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> will bring back the bones to their rest position, i.e. their position in *Edit* mode.

If you want to go back to a particular pose that is not the rest pose, you may be interested by the *Pose Library* that is in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data*.

You can create as many poses as you want, to create a pose, click on the "+" button, to recall a pose, click on the magnifying glass icon, to change a pose, click on the "+" button and choose *Replace Existing*.

Note that if you select one bone only and click on the magnifying glass, it will only recall the pose for this particular bone.

[image]